# Does Flyway have any way of including or excluding scripts?

Tags: flyway

In Flyway is there any way to mark certain scripts for inclusion or exclusion? What I am looking for is something similar to Liquibase's '[contexts](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/contexts.html)' feature, or Dbmaintains '[qualifiers](http://www.dbmaintain.org/tutorial.html#Qualifier_inclusion__exclusion)'. My primary use case is the test one that is outlined on the Liquibase site, a 'test' context where only scripts that are related to test data will run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Put those test scripts in a second folder, and selectively configure `flyway.locations` to include it.

Comment: Is script indexing per location with Flyway? i.e. if I have two locations defined can I use 1,2,3 and 1,2,3 in each of them? Or does it have to be 1 and 3 in the first folder, and 2 in the second folder?

Comment: 1 & 3 in the first, 2 in the second